# How are the formal definitions of curl interpreted? Where do they appear from and how to derive them?

Tags: definition, vector-fields, curl

So here are formal definitions of curl for [2dimensional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSAbk.png) and [3dimensional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcivY.png). Can someone please explain how to derive these and interpret them? I am familiar with limit definition of curl, however these seem difficult to me. I know how to derive 3dimensional curl from 2 dimensions so I would rather need 2 dimensional curl explained as if i understand where 2dimensional formula appears from i can understand the 3rd dimension myself. Please.

Comment: I recommend to think of it how [Green's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) and Stokes' theorem are related. The former is the 2d special case of the latter. If you work out the details it will become crystal clear why the curl differential operators in 2d and 3d are what they are.